# Unable to route a post request in express javascript with mongodb and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This is the ejs form which calls the route "/transaction-simulator"

```
                    <form action="/transaction-simulator" method="post" class="form-theme"> 
                        <label>Enter your own OTP</label>
                          <input type="tel" id="realOTP" placeholder="Enter Your OTP" class="input" maxlength="6">
                          <input type="button" class="btn" value="Use OTP" onclick="compute()">
                          <label>Or</label>
                          <input type="button" class="btn" onclick="generate()" value="Tap to generate an OTP">                                                                
                          <label>Enter your Secret OTP</label>
                          <input type="text" id="resOTP" placeholder="Enter Your Secret OTP" class="input">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Verify" >
                      </form>
```

This is the route in route.js which contains all other routes that work perfect but this route is giving a 404 error. Any suggestions would be really helpful, been stuck with this for 2 days.

```
  app.post("/transaction-simulator", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        var query = {
            "_id": req.param.user_id
        };

        var projection = {
            position: 1,
            operation: 1,
            userip: 1,
            _id: 0
        };

        db.collection('users').findOne(query, projection, function(err, user) {
            if (err) console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
            if (user) verifyOTP(user);
        });
        res.redirect("/profile");
    });
```

Comment: Did you try removing `isLoggedIn` temporarily to see if that is causing the 404?

Comment: No,  I'll give it a try

Comment: Didn't make any difference

Comment: If you insert a `console.log('here')` inside your `/transaction-simulator` route handler, does it show up in your console? Perhaps the redirect to `/profile` is actually causing the 404? Also, I think it is redirecting too early (it should probably only redirect if the user was found)?